# Reading XML in id="key" value="value" attribute format?

Tags: xml, extjs, extjs4

How can I read XML in the attribute format into a ExtJS Store, where key/values
are specified on one row as id/value?  I'm more familiar with the second format
given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMLResponse>
    <data>
        <row>
            <column id="title" value="Star Wars"/>
            <column id="director" value="Lucas"/>
            <column id="year" value="1977"/>
        </row>
        <row>
            <column id="title" value="Jaws"/>
            <column id="director" value="Spielberg"/>
            <column id="year" value="1975"/>
        </row>
    </data>
</XMLResponse>
```

The more traditional way of writing XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMLResponse>
    <data>
        <row>
            <title>Star Wars</title>
            <director>Lucas</director>
            <year>1977</year>
        </row>
        <row>
            <title>Jaws</title>
            <director>Spielberg</director>
            <year>1975</year>
        </row>
    </data>
</XMLResponse>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not very well-documented, but the mappings for your fields can be any expression accepted by [Ext.dom.Query](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Query). So where you'd normally have a simple mapping of "title" to select a child tag named "title", you can include a more complex selector. In this case, you want to select the "value" attribute of "column" tags whose ID attributes match the field name you're looking for, so in your model or store, you can define your fields like so:

```
fields: [
    { name: 'title', mapping: 'column[id=title]@value' },
    { name: 'director', mapping: 'column[id=director]@value' },
    { name: 'year', mapping: 'column[id=year]@value' }
],
```